# Caching issue with AEM dispatcher

Tags: aem, dispatcher

I have include load module in httpd.conf file as shown below.

```
LoadModule dispatcher_module libexec/apache2/dispatcher-apache2.4-4.2.0.so
```

Is it fine should it always be included as         `libexec/apache2/mod_dispatcher.so`

The docroot in the dispathcer.any file is configured as `/docroot "/var/log/apache2/cache"`

I am able to see the logs but the cache directory is empty (its not caching the content).

this is dispatcher.any

```
# Each farm configures a set of load balanced renders (i.e. remote servers)
/farms
  {
  # First farm entry
  /website 
    {  
    # Request headers that should be forwarded to the remote server.
    /clientheaders
      {
      # Forward all request headers that are end-to-end. If you want
      # to forward a specific set of headers, you'll have to list
      # them here.
      "*"
      }



 # Hostname globbing for farm selection (virtual domain addressing)
    /virtualhosts
      {
      # Entries will be compared against the "Host" request header
      # and an optional request URL prefix.
      #
      # Examples:
      #
      #   www.company.com
      #   intranet.*
      #   myhost:8888/mysite
      "*"
      }

    # The load will be balanced among these render instances
    /renders
      {
      /rend01
        {
        # Hostname or IP of the render
        /hostname "127.0.0.1"
        # Port of the render
        /port "4503"
        # Connect timeout in milliseconds, 0 to wait indefinitely
        # /timeout "0"
        }
      }

    # The filter section defines the requests that should be handled by the dispatcher.
    #
    # Entries can be either specified using globs, or elements of the request line:
    #
    # (1) globs will be compared against the entire request line, e.g.:
    #
    #       /0001 { /type "deny" /glob "* /index.html *" }
    #
    #     denies request "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" but not "GET /index.html?a=b HTTP/1.1".
    #
    # (2) method/url/query/protocol/path/selectors/extension/suffix will be compared
    #     against the respective elements of  the request line, e.g.:
    #
    #       /0001 { /type "deny" /method "GET" /url "/index.html" }
    #
    #     denies both "GET /index.html" and "GET /index.html?a=b HTTP/1.1".
    #
    # (3) all elements of the request line can also be specified as regular expressions,
    #     which are identified by using single quotes, e.g.
    #
    #       /0001 { /type "allow" /method '(GET|HEAD)' }
    #
    #     allows GET or HEAD requests, or:
    #
    #       /0002 { /type "deny" /extension '()' }
    #
    #     denies requests having no extension.
    #
    # Note: specifying elements of the request line is the preferred method.
    #
    /filter
      {
      # Deny everything first and then allow specific entries
      /0001 { /type "allow" /glob "*" }

      # Open consoles
#     /0011 { /type "allow" /url "/admin/*"  }  # allow servlet engine admin
#     /0012 { /type "allow" /url "/crx/*"    }  # allow content repository
#     /0013 { /type "allow" /url "/system/*" }  # allow OSGi console

      # Allow non-public content directories
#     /0021 { /type "allow" /url "/apps/*"   }  # allow apps access
#     /0022 { /type "allow" /url "/bin/*"    }
      /0023 { /type "allow" /url "/content*" }  # disable this rule to allow mapped content only

#     /0024 { /type "allow" /url "/libs/*"   }
#     /0025 { /type "deny"  /url "/libs/shindig/proxy*" } # if you enable /libs close access to proxy

#     /0026 { /type "allow" /url "/home/*"   }
#     /0027 { /type "allow" /url "/tmp/*"    }
#     /0028 { /type "allow" /url "/var/*"    }

      # Enable extensions in non-public content directories, using a regular expression
      /0041
        {
        /type "allow"
        /extension '(css|gif|ico|js|png|swf|jpe?g)'
        }
 /0042
        {
        /type "allow"
        /extension '(html)'
        }

      # Enable features 
      /0062 { /type "allow" /url "/libs/cq/personalization/*"  }  # enable personalization

      # Deny content grabbing, on all accessible pages, using regular expressions
      /0081
        {
        /type "deny"
        /selectors '((sys|doc)view|query|[0-9-]+)'
        /extension '(json|xml)'
        }
      # Deny content grabbing for /content
      /0082
        {
        /type "deny"
        /path "/content"
        /selectors '(feed|rss|pages|languages|blueprint|infinity|tidy)'
        /extension '(json|xml|html)'
        }

#     /0087 { /type "allow" /method "GET" /extension 'json' "*.1.json" }  # allow one-level json requests
      }

    # The cache section regulates what responses will be cached and where.
    /cache
      {
      # The docroot must be equal to the document root of the webserver. The
      # dispatcher will store files relative to this directory and subsequent
      # requests may be "declined" by the dispatcher, allowing the webserver
      # to deliver them just like static files.
      /docroot "/var/log/apache2/cache"

      # Sets the level upto which files named ".stat" will be created in the 
      # document root of the webserver. When an activation request for some 
      # page is received, only files within the same subtree are affected 
      # by the invalidation.
      #/statfileslevel "0"

      # Flag indicating whether to cache responses to requests that contain
      # authorization information.
      #/allowAuthorized "1"

      # Flag indicating whether the dispatcher should serve stale content if
      # no remote server is available.
      #/serveStaleOnError "0"

      # The rules section defines what responses should be cached based on
      # the requested URL. Please note that only the following requests can
      # lead to cacheable responses:
      #
      # - HTTP method is GET
      # - URL has an extension
      # - Request has no query string
      # - Request has no "Authorization" header (unless allowAuthorized is 1)
      /rules
        {
        /0000
          {
          # the globbing pattern to be compared against the url
          # example: *             -> everything
          #        : /foo/bar.*    -> only the /foo/bar documents
          #        : /foo/bar/*    -> all pages below /foo/bar
          #        : /foo/bar[./]* -> all pages below and /foo/bar itself
          #        : *.html        -> all .html files
          /glob "*"
          /type "allow"
          }
        }

      # The invalidate section defines the pages that are "invalidated" after
      # any activation. Please note that the activated page itself and all 
      # related documents are flushed on an modification. For example: if the 
      # page /foo/bar is activated, all /foo/bar.* files are removed from the
      # cache.
      /invalidate
        {
        /0000
          {
          /glob "*"
          /type "deny"
          }
        /0001
          {
          # Consider all HTML files stale after an activation.
          /glob "*.html"
          /type "allow"
          }
        /0002
          {
          /glob "/etc/segmentation.segment.js"
          /type "allow"
          }
        /0003
          {
          /glob "*/analytics.sitecatalyst.js"
          /type "allow"
          }
        }

      # The allowedClients section restricts the client IP addresses that are
      # allowed to issue activation requests.
      /allowedClients
        {
        # Uncomment the following to restrict activation requests to originate
        # from "localhost" only.
        #
        #/0000
        #  {
        #  /glob "*"
        #  /type "deny"
        #  }
        #/0001
        #  {
        #  /glob "127.0.0.1"
        #  /type "allow"
        #  }
        }

      # The ignoreUrlParams section contains query string parameter names that
      # should be ignored when determining whether some request's output can be
      # cached or delivered from cache.
      #
      # In this example configuration, the "q" parameter will be ignored. 
      #/ignoreUrlParams
      #  {
      #  /0001 { /glob "*" /type "deny" }
      #  /0002 { /glob "q" /type "allow" }
      #  }

      # Cache response headers next to a cached file. On the first request to
      # an uncached resource, all headers matching one of the values found here
      # are stored in a separate file, next to the cache file. On subsequent
      # requests to the cached resource, the stored headers are added to the
      # response.
      #
      # Note, that file globbing characters are not allowed here.
      #
      #/headers
      #  {
      #  "Cache-Control"
      #  "Content-Disposition"
      #  "Content-Type"
      #  "Expires"
      #  "Last-Modified"
      #  "X-Content-Type-Options"
      #  }

      # A grace period defines the number of seconds a stale, auto-invalidated
      # resource may still be served from the cache after the last activation
      # occurring. Auto-invalidated resources are invalidated by any activation,
      # when their path matches the /invalidate section above. This setting
      # can be used in a setup, where a batch of activations would otherwise
      # repeatedly invalidate the entire cache.
      #
      #/gracePeriod "2"

      # Enable TTL evaluates the response headers from the backend, and if they
      # contain a Cache-Control max-age or Expires date, an auxiliary, empty file
      # next to the cache file is created, with modification time equal to the
      # expiry date. When the cache file is requested past the modification time
      # it is automatically re-requested from the backend.
      #
      # /enableTTL "1"

      }

    # The statistics sections dictates how the load should be balanced among the
    # renders according to the media-type. 
    /statistics
      {
      /categories
        {
        /html
          {
          /glob "*.html"
          }
        /others
          {
          /glob "*"
          }
        }
      }

    # Authorization checker: before a page in the cache is delivered, a HEAD
    # request is sent to the URL specified in /url with the query string
    # '?uri='. If the response status is 200 (OK), the page is returned
    # from the cache. Otherwise, the request is forwarded to the render and
    # its response returned.
    #
    # Only pages matching the /filter section below are checked, all other pages
    # get delivered unchecked.
    #
    # All header lines returned from the auth_checker's HEAD request that match
    # the /headers section will be returned as well.
    #
    #/auth_checker
    #  {
    #  /url "/bin/permissioncheck.html"
    #  /filter
    #    {
    #    /0000
    #      {
    #      /glob "*"
    #      /type "deny"
    #      }
    #    /0001
    #      {
    #      /glob "*.html"
    #      /type "allow"
    #      }
    #    }
    #  /headers
    #    {
    #    /0000
    #      {
    #      /glob "*"
    #      /type "deny"
    #      }
    #    /0001
    #      {
    #      /glob "Set-Cookie:*"
    #      /type "allow"
    #      }
    #    }
    #  }

    }
  }
```

Comment: It really seems you didn't do much investigation around it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure the dispatcher mod as well. 
to enable caching you have to specifically configure the `/cache` section

to be more precise you need some "allows" in `/cache` -> `/rules` section.
easiest one:

`/0001 { /type "allow" /glob "*" }`

Read the manual: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html

Comment: I followed all the steps provided in this doc

Comment: I have configured /docroot "/var/log/apache2/cache" under /cache